# how to use my vimrc file when edit file width sudo command

Tags: sudo, vim

I found when i use the command `sudo vim /etc/www/main.wsgi` the vim said:

> neocomplcache disabled: "sudo vim" is detected and $HOME is set to your user's home. You may want to use the sudo.vim plugin, the "-H" option with "sudo" or set always_set_home in /etc/sudoers instead.
>   Press ENTER or type command to continue

and when i ENTER and edit file, the neocomplcache seems goes wrong function.

the i search the google, I found the command `vim sudo:/etc/www/main.wsgi` 
but it seems doesn't use my own .vimrc configure file.

so, what you others to do ?

Answer (score 5):

Add following mapping to your `vimrc`:

```
" Editing a protected file as 'sudo'
cmap W w !sudo tee % >/dev/null<CR>
```

Now edit the protected files as you normally do:

```
vim /etc/www/main.wsgi
```

but when you want to save the changes use `:W` instead of `:w`, `vim` will prompt for a `sudo` password, enter your `sudo` password and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. That's it!