# sudo is denied access to change keyboard backlight?

Tags: permissions, keyboard, root, samsung, backlight

**Opening vim as sudo -i or sudo - still doesn't let me write to the file.**

Trying to change the keyboard backlight settings on my laptop gives me this output; even with sudo I can't change anything in it. Even opening the file with sudo I can't change it and save it.

```
10:00:35  @ ・ー ・ 
cat sys/class/leds/samsung\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness 
4
10:01:28  @ ・ー ・ 
sudo echo '0' > sys/class/leds/samsung\:\:kbd_backlight/
brightness      device/         max_brightness  power/          subsystem/      trigger         uevent          
10:01:28  @ ・ー ・ 
sudo echo '0' > sys/class/leds/samsung\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness 
-bash: sys/class/leds/samsung::kbd_backlight/brightness: Permission denied
10:01:58  @ ・ー ・
```

Here are the permissions

```
10:04:15  @ ・ー ・ 
ll /sys/class/leds/samsung\:\:kbd_backlight/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    0 Oct 22 08:44 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    0 Oct 22 08:44 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Oct 22 08:44 brightness
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Oct 22 09:26 device -> ../../../samsung/
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Oct 22 08:44 max_brightness
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Oct 22 09:26 power/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Oct 22 09:26 subsystem -> ../../../../../class/leds/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Oct 22 09:26 trigger
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Oct 22 08:44 uevent
```

As you can guess, it's really annoying and it's also killing my battery.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When using sudo with redirection, I get 'permission denied'](http://askubuntu.com/questions/230476/when-using-sudo-with-redirection-i-get-permission-denied)

Comment: Except for the fact that editing the file with sudo vim, gives me permission denied as well.

Comment: I found [how to use my vimrc file when edit file width sudo command](http://askubuntu.com/questions/351451/how-to-use-my-vimrc-file-when-edit-file-width-sudo-command)

Comment: When I try to edit the file with vim, in super user mode; I can not save. It gives me permission denied.

Comment: In order to know if is a vim problem, could you test if another editor with sudo works? Also, could you post `:!echo "$HOME"` vim command output? I guess that running `sudo vim` the context environment is not right.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo su -
```

this will change you to root, and try it this way. 
Sometimes I observed that this way I have more rights than simply with sudo

Answer (score 0):

You can't write like that through a file descriptor using sudo, the echo runs as root, the output it generates does not. You must use **sudo tee** to elevate the access, example:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee [path to sysfs]
```

You can even append with tee using the **-a** switch. I do this all the time with ftrace.

```
echo 'nvme_submit_request'  | sudo tee ${TRACE}/set_ftrace_filter
echo 'nvme_isr'             | sudo tee -a ${TRACE}/set_ftrace_filter
echo 'nvme_process_sglist'  | sudo tee -a ${TRACE}/set_ftrace_filter
```